# Pass data from Root (app) Componenet to route component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I want to make an API call by using a service call from within my app's root component (AppComponent). The resulting data needs to be displayed by one or more other (child) components that are controlled by the RouterModule. For example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _myService: MyService){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._myService.getSomeData().subscribe(theData => {
      // theData needs to be displayed in ChildComponenet1 and / or ChildComponent2
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

And my AppModule sets up routes using RouterModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'child-component-1', component: ChildComponent1 },
      { path: 'child-component-2', component: ChildComponent2 },
    ]),
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to avoid making an http request every time a user navigates to a /child-component, which is why I need to load the data from the AppComponent. (Or maybe I am approaching this the wrong way?)

This must be a fairly common pattern, any advice on the best way to approach this would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It may be best to have your `MyService` cache the data, say in a local variable in the service. Then, when you inject the service into your child components, and it calls a service function, the service checks the local variable. If something is in the variable, use it, if not, load the data and cache it for later use. Since the service is a singleton, the data should only load once unless you create some mechanism to timeout the value.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried something similar but I had the local variable in the Child Component class instead of the service, which did not work since the Component is destroyed / re-initialized on navigation to / from. I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just a simple app then what was suggested above to use a Service would be the best approach.

Another approach would be to have a look at state management using [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store).

Here's an example of how you would do it (untested):

```
// data.ts
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const STOREDATA = 'STORE_DATA';

export function dataReducer(state: data = null, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case STOREDATA:
            return action.payload;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In your app's main module, import those reducers and use the StoreModule.provideStore(reducers) function to provide them to Angular's injector:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { dataReducer } from './data';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore({ data: dataReducer })
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your AppComponent

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { STOREDATA } from './data';

interface AppState {
  data: any;
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private _myService: MyService, private store: Store<AppState>){ }

   ngOnInit() {
       this._myService.getSomeData().subscribe(theData => {               
          this.store.dispatch({ type: STOREDATA, payload: theData });
       }, err => {
            console.log(err);
       });
   }
}
```

In you child component:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { STOREDATA } from './data';

interface AppState {
  data: any;
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   public data:any;

   constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){ 
       this.data = this.store.select('data');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation and this example, definitely helpful. I had used Redux in React apps but never with Angular2. I ended up going this route. One difference is I am using a service class to make the http requests and dispatch the reducer functions on success. But the concept is essentially the same :)